# how to create one simple alert if crosser horizonal line?

Tags: pine-script

i tried my best to make it work but i get errors every time:(.. i just want to create a simple alert once the price start crossing up and crossing Down the Horizon Line by 2% will trigger the alert.. so far this is my code but i know that i missed up if you can please guide me to make it right
***(Breakup and Breakdown is a Horizon Lines that i renamed)***

```
//@version=3
study(title="Alert", overlay=true)

up  = Breakup(close, 2%)
down  = Breakdown(close, 2%)

alertcondition(condition=crossover(close, up), title="Cross Up", message="Breakup")

alertcondition(condition=crossunder(close, down), title="Cross Down", message="Breakdown")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just calculate `price + 2%` and `price - 2%` and use those values in your cross conditions.

Say your target price is 100:

```
target_price = 100
per = 0.02  // 2%
target_up = target_price * (1 + per)
target_down = target_price * (1 - per)

is_cross_up = crossover(close, target_up)
is_cross_dwn = crossunder(close, target_down)

alertcondition(is_cross_up, "Cross Up")
alertconditino(is_cross_dwn, "Cross Down")
```

Comment: thank you for sir for your answer.. I'm having error (failed, reason: The script must have at least one output function call (e.g. plot, barcolor, etc.). Reason: AST is Empty)m may by using the target price is it means that the code will still seal with the Horizon line i Draw,, thank u so much again sir

Comment: Pinescript does not have access to user drawn objects. You have to enter the value manually. You can use a user input.